# What is the advantage of positional encoding over using additional features?

Tags: neural-network, time-series, transformer, encoding

Popular models such as the transformer model use positional encoding on existing feature dimensions. Why is this preferred over adding more features to the feature dimension of the tensor which can hold the positional information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a Transformer model, why does one sum positional encoding to the embedding rather than concatenate it?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55901/in-a-transformer-model-why-does-one-sum-positional-encoding-to-the-embedding-ra)